# Ribbon buttons gray but working

Tags: 2010, ribbon

SharePoint 2010

Just recently a problem has cropped up where the entire ribbon on one site is grayed out as if it were deactivated, but the buttons still function normally. This isn't a huge problem, but it's bothersome to the clients who don't realize they can still use the buttons despite their appearance. So far it looks like an IE10 issue, but I'm waiting on responses from other clients to compare different browser versions. FF20 seems to work fine.

Has anyone ever seen this before? I can't find any relevant results on Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried enforcing their being enabled in code? Something like the following should help to do this:

```
<div class="article-content">
    <PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField FieldName="Body" HasInitialFocus="True" MinimumEditHeight="400px" runat="server"
        AllowHtmlSourceEditing="false"
        AllowFontsMenu="true"
        AllowFontColorsMenu="true"
        AllowImages="true"
        AllowHeadings="true"
        AllowStyles="true"
        AllowTables="true"
        AllowReusableContent="true"/>
</div>
```

Alternatively you could test if this is an IE10 issue by changing your user agent string.  T o do this in IE10 press F12 to bring up the developer tools, and force the User Agent string to IE 8:

[image]

If so it's a messy workaround for users, but something and it will provide additional direction within here to help us diagnose the issue better with you.

Comment: This process led me to the issue, things were getting hung up on a custom feature that wasn't playing nice with IE10. I removed the feature, acquired a new copy of it (deviantpoint.downloadzip), tweaked it a little in VS to match my environment, re-deployed and now everything is back to normal. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues with SP2010 / IE10 (try a Google or Bing search), and Microsoft plans to fix this with the next service pack (SP2). Currently, only the SP2 preview has been released.

One explanation could be that you have a script error in your page that prevents later scripts - including the one that makes the ribbon buttons selectable - from running. In this case, using the IE10 Developer Tools (F12) to debug the page or following @ElvisLikeBear's suggestion might help.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll be looking for that service pack! Looks like it fixes a handful of other things I've encountered too.